# php namespace keyword with no name specified

Tags: php, namespaces

I saw a piece of php code I don't understand. It uses the namespace keyword without specifying a name

```
namespace {
//code
}
```

What is the purpose of this?

It's from a `password_hash` polyfill for `php5.4-`

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php

Comment: If you click the line number in github you can select "view git blame" directly to see the comment for the commit where that code was added

Comment: It's a namespaced file for the global namespace

Comment: @JimL I don't understand the comment, **Move binary implementation to separate namespace (to avoid polluting the global namespace with non-core functions)** I don't understand the purpose of putting something in a namespace without a name

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't know what you mean

Comment: I mean that it's a file with a namespace keyword; but unless you provide a namespace name, then it uses the global namespace

Comment: @MarkBaker So that's kind of what I thought, using the namespace keyword without specifying a name seems to be equivalent to not using the keyword at all?